# Glimpse is breaking signalr on mono

Tags: c#, asp.net, mono, signalr, glimpse

After installing Glimpse, 
my ~/signalr/hubs stopped working at Mono productions server. 
However it still works when running locally using IIS Express.

```
System.ArgumentNullException
Argument cannot be null.
Parameter name: httpContext

 at System.Web.HttpContextWrapper..ctor (System.Web.HttpContext httpContext) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Glimpse.AspNet.AspNetFrameworkProvider.get_Context () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Glimpse.AspNet.AspNetFrameworkProvider.get_HttpRequestStore () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Glimpse.Core.Framework.GlimpseRuntime.GetRuntimePolicy (RuntimeEvent runtimeEvent) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Glimpse.Core.Framework.GlimpseRuntime.HasOffRuntimePolicy (RuntimeEvent policyName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Glimpse.Core.Framework.GlimpseRuntime.EndSessionAccess () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Glimpse.AspNet.HttpModule.EndSessionAccess (System.Web.HttpContextBase httpContext) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Glimpse.AspNet.HttpModule.<Init>b__2 (System.Object context, System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.HttpApplication+<RunHooks>c__Iterator5.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.HttpApplication+<Pipeline>c__Iterator6.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.Tick () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I dont need to view signalr requests, so turning the diagnostics off would also solve my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable Glimpse for a given set of URI's in your `web.config`.

Take a look at the URI section of [our configuration docs](http://getglimpse.com/Help/Configuration) to see how to make the change.